Potrace - trace only required points
I have successfully used Potrace to convert a png image to an eps file.
The png image contains only horizontal and vertical lines, but the Potrace
eps output shows points midway between lines. I'm new to eps files so
perhaps this is normal but I dont understand how these mid-points
contribute to the shape and it seems like they could be omitted. Any help
is appreciated!


From my point of view, this shape can be defined by only12 points, but again perhaps my understanding is limited here on how eps files work.

Not really sure what the question here is. I'm not familiar with ProTrace, but yes. For vector drawing, only 4 points are needed to define a rectangle. Midpoints are superfluous.

My questions is how can I use potrace (software to convert bitmap to vector) in such a way that does not have superfluous points in a straight line.

No, but I just tried it and it does not produce any difference.

Hi I appreciate your suggestion, but I workflow requires command line.
